# ¿Como manejar fecha en Python, Sqlite3. la fecha esta almacenada como vachar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

quisiera exponer un problema que tengo con comparación de fechas en Python y Sqlite3, estoy tratando de filtrar por fechas de una tabla donde almaceno la fecha como una cadena Vachar(10), aquí el problema. Agradezco de antemano la ayuda u orientación.

Acá obtengo la fecha del día y sumo días para obtener fecha final (self.fecha_new1), donde me da un fecha posterior

```
def sumar_dias2(self, *args):
        dias=0
        self.combo=StringVar()
        if self.combo_recordar.get() == "7 Días":
            dias=7
        elif self.combo_recordar.get() == "15 Días":
            dias=15
        elif self.combo_recordar.get() == "1 Mes":
            dias=30
        elif self.combo_recordar.get() == "3 Meses":
            dias=90
        elif self.combo_recordar.get() == "Todos":
            dias=0
        self.hoy=datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y") # Convierte en cadena
        hoy1 = datetime.strptime(self.hoy, "%d/%m/%Y") # Convierte en datetime
        self.fecha_new = hoy1 + timedelta(days=dias)
        self.fecha_new1=datetime.strftime(self.fecha_new, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Aqui obtengo la fecha actual (hoy)

```
def convertir_fecha(self):
    self.fecha_hoy=datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y") # Convierte en cadena
    self.fecha_hoy1 = datetime.strptime(self.fecha_hoy, "%d/%m/%Y") # Convierte en datetime
```

Aquí genero el reporte, donde trato de filtrar entre la fecha de hoy y la fecha posterior, no me generar error, simplemente no emite nada. La tabla está en Sqlite3 y la variable se almacena como tipo Vachar(10)

```
def get_recordatorios_dias(self):
    #Limpiando la Tabla
    records = self.tree4.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree4.delete(element)
    #consultando lo datos
    fecha1=datetime.strptime(self.fecha_hoy, "%d/%m/%Y")
    fecha2=datetime.strptime(self.fecha_new1, "%d/%m/%Y")
    self.fecha11=fecha1.date()
    self.fecha22=fecha2.date()
    print(type(self.fecha11))
    print(type(self.fecha22))
    print(self.fecha11)
    print(self.fecha22)
    query = 'SELECT * FROM recordatorios WHERE date(FECHA_RECOR) BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY APELLIDO1_RECOR' 
    parameters=(self.fecha11, self.fecha22)
    db_rows = self.run_query(query, parameters)
    #Rellenando los Datos
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree4.insert('', 0, text = row[0], value=row[1:10]) #, tags='cero')
```

Acá tengo mi consulta

```
# Consulta
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result
    #return [rec for rec in result]
```

Yo estoy manejando fechas en el formato días / mes / año, 30/07/2021 y lo guardo como una cadena en la tabla, hasta alli perfecto, (Sqlite3), el problema es que cuando quiero generar un informe, reporte, basado en rangos de fechas, no lo ordena por fecha, he tratado de convertir las fechas parametros ingresada por el usuario en tipo datetime(), lo he intentado como cadena y simplemente no le ordena, he leído y probado varias opciones, pero ya no sé dónde encontrar respuestas, si alguien me entiende o tiene una idea para ayudar, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Estaba escribiendo una respuesta cuando pusiste la tuya, pero igual la expondré. Tu problema es un problema de lógica en cómo se manejan los strings. SIEMPRE guarda los valores en bases de datos en formato `YYYY-MM-DD` (o `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`).

El motivo es que, tal como los números, los caracteres también tienen un valor que puede ser mayor o menor que otro. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> 'a' > 'b'
False
>>> 'b' > 'a'
True
>>> 10 > 2
True
>>> '10' > '2'
False # Qué?
# El primer caracter de la primera cadena es menor que '2'
>>> '28/06/2021' > '03/07/2021'
True # <- Valor equivocado
>>> '2021-06-28' > '2021-07-02'
False # <- Valor correcto
```

El motor de la base de datos también funciona de la misma manera.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, excelente explicación, comprendo mejor el porque de la solución

Answer (score 0):

Conseguí esta solución, "Con SQLite utilice siempre el formato AAAA-MM-DD para almacenar fechas de texto."
Para solucionar mi problema, cambie la forma de almacenar la fecha de dia/mes/año a año/mes/dia 2021-07-30, y con esto ya me filtra y trabajo perfecto con el SQLite3 y la funciones strftime() y date().